# Disable Billing information step from checkout magento

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I run a Magento Shop that has only virtual products in my store.Its rather annyoing for many people to enter billing information although they are only buying virtual products and we don't need a billing info. so i want to remove billing adress from checkout onepage but i can't pass to the next step. i've changed the order of steps in checkout, i set payment as first steps but payments methods are not loaded.

any help would be thanksfull !

Comment: If you would have created your products the right way (virtual products and not, I guess simple products) you would not have that problem... If a cart only have virtual products in it, billing information is not required

Comment: yes my cart has only virtual products , is there an option to make billing information not required from the admin?